# How to add an object into another object - ES5

Tags: javascript, controller, commerce-cloud, es6

```
var filters = {'sort': 'asc', 'query': 'id=1'};
var data = {};
data.search = {'type': 'manual'};
Object.assign(data.search, filters);
```

When using ES6 this code works correctly. But when it's in ES5 I get this error:

> *Cannot find function assign in object function Object()*

What can be an alternative to this in ES5 javascript?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are you using ES5? Are your tags correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To comply with ES5 and effectively combine the two objects (seems to push one object to another object). We can use this:

```
for (var key in availabilityDetails.search) {
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(availabilityDetails.search, key)) {
        data.search[key] = availabilityDetails.search[key];
    }
}
```